# SHFileOperation returns 1223, only on xp

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-xp

I have a little console application to copy all files from one usb drive to another:

```
void CopyAllFiles(wchar_t** source, wchar_t* destination)
{
    WCHAR src[MAX_PATH + 1], dest[MAX_PATH + 1];
    wsprintf(src, L"%s*\0", *source);
    src[wcslen(src) + 1] = 0;             \\Just to be sure it ends with "\0\0"
    wsprintf(dest, L"%s\0", destination);
    dest[wcslen(dest) + 1] = 0;

    cout << "Source: " << src << endl << "Destination: " << dest << endl;

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT s = { 0 };
    s.hwnd = nullptr;
    s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS | FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION | ;
    s.pTo = dest;
    s.pFrom = src;
    cerr << "SHFileOperation returns " << SHFileOperation(&s) << endl;
}
```

This works great on Windows 8.1, but when I try to run it on WinXP with same configuration, SHFileOperation returns 1223. I try to copy 1GB from 4GB USB to empty 64GB USB.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What you should be doing is hardcoding the names and verifying that the file names you're using are 1) correct, and 2) exist, and cut the top half of that code out.  For all we know, those file names and directories are bogus or if not bogus, *relative* names that do not resolve to where you think they should be resolving to.

Comment: That's ERROR_CANCELLED, strangely

Comment: I am wondering how this is interpreted "FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION | ;" (extra |)

Comment: With all of those "NOCONFIRM" and "SILENT" flags, the OP has turned off any visible way of finding out what happened.

Comment: `wsprintf(src, L"%s*\0", *source);` and `wsprintf(dest, L"%s\0", destination);` do not copy the extra null terminators. This code is also buffer overflows waiting to happen. Since you are using C++ anyway, I would suggest using `std::wstring` instead of `WCHAR[]`.

Comment: `\\Just to be sure it ends with "\0\0"` makes what's there non-compilable.  Can you double check that the code matches what has successfully run through a compiler?  I'd be sad if someone answered fixing something that wasn't actually the problem in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't realize I have to specify path to existing directory - on Win8 it automatically creates the directory, on xp it doesn't.

Big thanks to all of you guys for help and suggestions.